# Quasiconvex functions definition

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Quoting from Boyd and Vanderberghe Convex Optimization-

For a function on R, quasiconvexity requires that each sublevel set be an interval
(including, possibly, an infinite interval). An example of a quasiconvex function on
R is shown in figure 3.9.

Figure 3.9 A quasiconvex function on R. For each α, the α-sublevel set Sα
is convex, i.e., an interval. The sublevel set Sα is the interval [a, b]. The
sublevel set Sβ is the interval (−∞, c].

I have a doubt in this. What exactly is meant by the fact that every sublevel set is an interval?
I didnt really understand this explanation of quasiconvex functions and how to use this to test it.

Comment: there seems to be some information missing in your post

Comment: The general definition (including for multivariate functions) is that all sublevel sets are convex. Now: what are the convex sets in $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example. Take $f(x) = \log(x)$ on the domain $x > 0$. Every sublevel set $S_\alpha$ of this function is:

$$
S_\alpha = \{ x > 0 : \log(x) \leq \alpha \} = \{ x > 0 : x \leq e^{\alpha} \} = (0, e^{\alpha}]
$$

So in this case, the sublevel sets are indeed intervals, and $\log(x)$ is quasiconvex on $x > 0$.

Now, take for example $f(x) = x^3 + 3x^2$. Taking $\alpha = 2$ we have

$$
S_2 = \{ x : x^3 + 3x^2 \leq 2 \} = [-1, \sqrt{3}-1] \cup (-\infty, -\sqrt{3}-1]
$$
which is clearly not an interval (see the picture below). Thus, the function is **not** quasiconvex, since it has at least one sublevel set which is not an interval.

[image]

Comment: Ok so i am to understand that the inteval [be it finite or not...i.e till infinity etc] is one whole interval not any union etc.

Comment: Exactly. Intervals are the only convex sets on the real line, so it coincides with the general definition on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Thanks man . Was very helpful